# Normal Distribution with Normally Distributed Mean

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I am looking to determine the distribution of $X$, given:

$Y \sim N(29.5, 6.49)$

$X \sim N(y, 0.16)$

Where $y$ is sampled from $Y$.

edit: I am working on a project attempting to determine a confidence regarding the achieved soil strength. I have an assumed distribution of the strength, and know the variance of the test procedure. To update the in-situ soil strength, I am looking to determine a distribution for the test strength: ie. test strength is comparatively a "sample" of the normally distributed in-situ strength.

Comment: The simplest way IMO is to use the characteristic function approach, along with conditional expectation. $$\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}|Y]]$$ and use the [known expression of the cf for Gaussians.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples)

Comment: See e.g., [this question on Stats.SE](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/211271/gaussian-with-a-gaussian-mean) for confirmation of the answer.

Comment: To those who voted to close as "This question is missing context or other details" -- additional context has been added by the OP. Worth revisiting, maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way (IMO) is to use the characteristic function approach, along with conditional expectation. $$\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}|Y]]$$ and use the [known expression of the cf for Gaussians.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_function_(probability_theory)#Examples) This yields the answer with one line of derivation.

---

**In more detail:** (put your mouse over the hidden text to reveal it)

> Let $\mu = 29.5$, $\sigma_Y=6.49$, $\sigma_X=0.16$. for every $t\in\mathbb{R}$, $$\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}]=\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[e^{itX}|Y]]=\mathbb{E}[e^{itY-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2t^2}]=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2t^2}\mathbb{E}[e^{itY}]=e^{-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_X^2t^2}e^{it\mu-\frac{1}{2}\sigma_Y^2t^2}=\boxed{e^{it\mu-\frac{1}{2}(\sigma_Y^2+\sigma_X^2)t^2}} $$so $X$ is distributed as a Normal with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2 = \sigma_Y^2+\sigma_X^2$.

Comment: So in the end it matches the intuitive result $Y+Z$ where $Z\sim N(0, 0.16)$.

Comment: @DavidK Yes, it does.

Comment: @Clement C. Thanks! This derivation does make sense to me. I just have one clarification (potentially silly question): Obviously since X is sampled from Y, the resulting distribution of X is highly dependent on Y. Therefore, I just want to confirm that the above derivation does not assume they are independent?.

Comment: @canucks101 It doesn't assume independence (which would have been a big problem indeed). The only things used are the [law of total expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) and the expression of a Gaussian characteristic function.

Comment: @Clement C. Many thanks for the thorough response and time taken to reply!

Comment: @canucks101 You're welcome. Good luck with your project!

Answer (score 1):

The density function for $X$ is $f_X(x)=\frac{1}{2\pi \sigma_x\sigma_y}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{(x-y)^2}{2\sigma_x^2}}e^{-\frac{(y-\mu_y)^2}{2\sigma_y^2}}dy$.

Here $\mu_y=29.5$, $\sigma_y=6.49$, and $\sigma_x=0.16$

Comment: That's not the final result, and doesn't come with any derivation...

Comment: The expression is simply the distribution for $X$ averaged over the distribution for $Y$.

Comment: Yes it is, and it is a partial result towards the solution. If someone asks "what is $72/4$," answering "it's equal to $36/2$" is not false, it's just... not the end answer.

Comment: Thanks for the input!